# Loading data range or string from excel file to an array then split in array

Tags: vba, excel

Is there someone can help me? I have here code that can duplicate entire row to have 2 rows. After duplicating the first entire row , I want to load string from range "G"  into array so that I can get certain string that Am planning to insert in "Thickness" and "width" column for me to use to calculate the "Weight" of the "Profile Type". If you will see I have an array in the code .But that array work differently for me and I had a hard time fulfilling the requirements I need.  The array in my code split the String using "X" as delimiter . Once the string was split it will add another cells for each split string. what I want is to do the split not in the column but in the array only so that I can maintain the data in G . I will use the string assigned in the array to get "Thickness and Width" of the profile which is "15 as Thickness and 150 as width". If there's any way to do same thing using other code it will be more helpful to simplify the code. 
Reminder that Profiletype string vary its length . Sometimes profile width are 4 digits (LB1000X4500X12/15)

Below are the snapshot of my worksheet for you to identify what the result will be.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Dim lastrow As Long
Dim i As Integer
Dim icount As Integer
Dim x As Long

    For x = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.CountLarge To 1 Step -1

        If Cells(x, "F") = "LB" Then
        Cells(x, "F") = "ComP"
        Cells(x + 1, "F").EntireRow.Insert
        Cells(x, "F").EntireRow.Copy Cells(x + 1, "F").EntireRow

        'array
        'Columns("G:G").NumberFormat = "@"
        Dim c As Long, r As Range, v As Variant, d As Variant

    For i = 2 To Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row '2 to 16 cell
        'v = Split (range("G" & i), "X")
        v = Split((Cells(x, "G") & i), "x")
        c = c + UBound(v) + 1

    'Next i


    For i = 2 To c

        If Range("G" & i) <> "" Then
            Set r = Range("G" & i)
            Dim arr As Variant
            arr = Split(r, "X")
            Dim j As Long
            r = arr(0)

    For j = 1 To UBound(arr)

        Rows(r.Row + j & ":" & r.Row + j).Insert Shift:=xlDown
        r.Offset(j, 0) = arr(j)
        r.Offset(j, -1) = r.Offset(0, -1)
        r.Offset(j, -2) = r.Offset(0, -2)

    Next j

        End If
    Next i
End If
Next x


End Sub
```

[image: preliminary format]

[image: correct result]

[image: wrong result]

[image]

Comment: Similar question by same author: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48031389/split-string-in-array-not-in-cell-range-vba

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works without duplication.

```
Sub test2()
    Dim vDB, vR()
    Dim i As Long, n As Long, k As Long, j As Integer
    Dim r As Integer
    Dim s As String
    vDB = Range("A2", "K" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
    n = UBound(vDB, 1)

    For i = 1 To n
        If vDB(i, 6) = "LB" Then
            r = 2
        Else
            r = 1
        End If
        k = k + r
        ReDim Preserve vR(1 To 11, 1 To k)
        s = vDB(i, 7)
        For j = 1 To 11
            If r = 1 Then
                vR(j, k) = vDB(i, j)
            Else
                vR(j, k - 1) = vDB(i, j)
                vR(j, k) = vDB(i, j)
            End If
        Next j
        If r = 2 Then
            vR(6, k - 1) = "comp"
            vR(6, k) = "comp"
            vR(8, k) = Split(s, "/")(1)
            vR(9, k) = Split(s, "X")(1)
            vR(9, k - 1) = vR(9, k - 1) - vR(8, k)
            vR(11, k - 1) = (vR(8, k - 1) * vR(9, k - 1) * vR(10, k - 1) * 7.85) / 10 ^ 6 '<~~ k2 weight
            vR(11, k) = (vR(8, k) * vR(9, k) * vR(10, k) * 7.85) / 10 ^ 6 '<~~ k3 weight
        End If
    Next i
    Range("f1") = "Type"
    Range("a2").Resize(k, 11) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(vR)

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Dy. Lee . it is working . I should have that condition . I will try more to study this one because i am just really new about vba . Thanks a lot and have a nice day..

Comment: @sayjon, Happy new year!

Comment: Happy New Year too.. ^_^

Comment: Hi Dy.Lee I have another question . How can I get the array value ? because I need to subtract value of  vR(8, k) which is thickness = 15 to vR(9, k) which is 450  to have 435 value and put in cell I2 ,same with the weight (LXWXH) . I am new with array I tried .value but its not working. hopefully you can help me .sorry for disturbing you again. Thank you.

Comment: @sayjon, i2 is to be 435?   450-15=435?

Comment: Hi Dy.Lee Yup, the original row for all " i " have the result of different of with of original row minus thickness of the duplicated row .Therefore i2-h3 = i2..

Comment: Therefore i2-h3 = i3 ?

Comment: Hi Dy.Lee It got the result in i3 and in i2 . I am trying to troubleshoot. it should be I i2 .there 450 will be superseded by 435..

Comment: original cell i2(450) also  to be 435?

Comment: yup it means 450 will be superseded by 435. i3 is 150 not 450 because 450 is i2.. sorry if I give you some confusion.

Comment: @sayjon,  I modified post again.

Comment: Dy.Lee . it is working now . I think I really need to be more analytical. thanks for your help . I will try to get weight also ... I will try if I can haha !!! thanks a lot for your great help.. highly appreciated.

Comment: @sayjon, you are welcome.  What is the formula for gaining weight?

Comment: Hi Dy. Lee weight =( thickness X width X Length *7.85) /1000000. I am trying it now . I just have hard time in identifying the right array. the original row and the duplicated one are both need to be calculated..

Comment: That is simple. Later  i will modify code. I am  busy now.

Comment: @sayjon, The weight will be the same as the code.. I modified code.

Comment: Hi Dy.Lee yup i managed the code for weight just need time for me to check the array . And for the added code thanks again ... the things you've shared is highly appreciated. Thank you very much..

Answer (score 2):

Does this do what you want? Run in copy of workbook to be safe.

```
Option explicit

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

'Bit redundant, would be better if you fully qualify workbook and worksheet with actual names.'
Dim TargetWorksheet as worksheet
Set TargetWorksheet = Activesheet 

With application
.screenupdating = false
.calculation = xlcalculationmanual
End with


With TargetWorksheet

.range("G:G").numberformat = "@"

Dim RowIndex As Long

For RowIndex = .usedrange.rows.countlarge to 1 step -1

If .Cells(RowIndex, "F").value2 = "LB" Then

.Cells(RowIndex, "F").value2 = "ComP"
.Cells(RowIndex + 1, "F").EntireRow.Insert
.Cells(RowIndex, "F").EntireRow.Copy .Cells(RowIndex + 1, "F").EntireRow

Dim SplitProfileType() as string
SplitProfileType = split(mid(.cells(RowIndex+1,"G").value2,3), "X") ' assumes first two characters will always be LB, that it is safe to ignore them and start from third character.'

' Write thickness'
.cells(RowIndex+1, "H").value2 = cdbl(mid(SplitProfileType(ubound(SplitProfileType)),instrrev(SplitProfileType(ubound(SplitProfileType)),"/",-1,vbbinarycompare)+1)

' Write width'
.cells(RowIndex+1, "i").value2 = cdbl(SplitProfileType(1))

    ' Calculate weight'
.cells(RowIndex+1,"K").value2 = .cells(RowIndex+1,"H").value2 * .cells(RowIndex+1,"I").value2 * .cells(RowIndex+1,"J").value2

End if

' I think because you are inserting a row below (rather than above/before), your RowIndex remains unaffected and no adjustment is needed to code. I could be wrong. I would need to test it to be sure.'

Next rowindex

End with

With application
.screenupdating = true
.calculation = xlcalculationautomatic
End with

End sub
```

Untested as written on mobile.

Comment: Hi Chilin .. your code is working . Only thing is that the newly added was added above. But that one will be ok as long as I have the correct data for Thickness and width. Another thing . Let we say I will add formula for weight which is WEIGHT = length x width x height. In which portion of the code should I put to make it appear correctly  base on the newly added thickness and width. The condition will be the same the old data need tor remain untouched. Thank  you . Your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: I recommend copy and pasting the whole thing again, as I&#39;ve edited different parts of the code. Let me know if the newly added is now on the row below -- and if the weight is calculated correctly.

Comment: I will try . But what do you mean  " I&#39;ve " ? Quite blurred for me . Sorry.

Comment: Sorry, it said: I recommend copy and pasting the whole thing again, as I've edited different parts of the code. Let me know if the newly added is now on the row below -- and if the weight is calculated correctly.

Comment: Hi Chillin Done testing it worked well. Your split code is a great help for me... Thank you and Highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It is faster to use an array than to enter it one-to-one in a cell.

```
Sub test()
    Dim vDB, vR()
    Dim i As Long, n As Long, k As Long, j As Integer
    Dim s As String
    vDB = Range("A2", "K" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
    n = UBound(vDB, 1)
    ReDim vR(1 To n * 2, 1 To 11)

    For i = 1 To n
        k = k + 2
        s = vDB(i, 7)
        For j = 1 To 11
            vR(k - 1, j) = vDB(i, j)
            vR(k, j) = vDB(i, j)
        Next j
        vR(k - 1, 6) = "comp"
        vR(k, 6) = "comp"
        vR(k, 8) = Split(s, "/")(1)
        vR(k, 9) = Split(s, "X")(1)
        vR(k, 11) = Empty '<~~ This is calculated Weight value place
    Next i
    Range("f1") = "Type"
    Range("a2").Resize(n * 2, 11) = vR

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Dy.Lee .Thanks for this . But why did you use K and A as reference for the range?

Comment: your data range's column is from "A" column to "k" column.

Comment: Hi Dy.Lee . I just try you r code. I encounter an error sunscript out of range in vR(k, 8) = Split(s, "/")(1).

Comment: Have all of your  data  string  "/" ? if  doesn't, occur error.

Comment: The data that has "/" is in Column G . But I have a header which dont have. My two data are LB450X150X11.5/15 and LB5500X2500X21.5/25.

Comment: Hi Dy.Lee . I just attached another snapshot (last picture) in this thread. Can you check that one? that is my table now I just make it one row. maybe we have different table format. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Hi Dy.Lee . I think it's ok now . I just create new sheet. I think theres somethng wrong with my table. I working  ... Thank you for your great contribution its a big learning for me.

Comment: I'm glad you're fine.

Comment: Hi Dy.Lee Can I ask more added info. Because I am doing the testing using a  command button. Let we say i run it automatically , is there's a case that the code will duplicate the data in multiple times? Because I try to click many times the data are still duplicating . what code I need to add if in case I want it to limit the duplicate process only once If "LB" was superseded already by comp. I mean if there's no LB anymore no duplication will happen.

Comment: I posted another method.

Comment: Hi Dy.Lee . yah i already test your code . its a great help thank you.