# Split string in array not in cell range vba

Tags: vba, excel

I am just new in creating macro and I have a macro that my colleague created which we used in our work . Now she is working with us and I need to do some changes.

Is it possible to get part of string in a string from other range to other cells? IS there's any code available for this? I think I need to split the data I need from column G to have the right result for column H and I. If there's any good help thank you in Advance.
example:

**column G**

SD230X200X45/20

SD5000X2000X40/25

**column H**

20           <--(string get from G)

25           <--(string get from G)

**column I**

200          <--(string get from G)

2000         <--(string get from G)

Comment: Similar question by same author: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48030819/loading-data-range-or-string-from-excel-file-to-an-array-then-split-in-array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do like this.

```
Sub test()
    Dim vDB, vR()
    Dim i As Long, n As Long
    Dim s As String
    vDB = Range("g1", Range("g" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    n = UBound(vDB, 1)
    ReDim vR(1 To n, 1 To 2)

    For i = 1 To n
        s = vDB(i, 1)
        vR(i, 1) = Split(s, "/")(1)
        vR(i, 2) = Split(s, "X")(1)
    Next i
    Range("h1").Resize(n, 2) = vR

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Dy.Lee I will test this one first . Thank you.

Comment: Hi Dy.Lee your code got an error . But I will close this one . I got solution already . Thank you and highly appreciated.

Comment: @sayjon The answer is not just for your benefit, but for other users who have a similar question in the future.  So, to enable the answer to be corrected for those future users, it would help if you gave more information than "your code got an error".  What was the error message?  Which line did it occur on?

Comment: Hi @YowE3K error is subscript out of range . It's pertaining about this code vR(i, 1) = Split(s, "/")(1). Thank you

Comment: @sayjon What was the data in column G for the row represented by the variable `i`?  (Or, what is the value of `s`?)  If you had the data you show in the question, I can't see why that would give an error. (The error is implying there is no "/" in your data.)

Comment: Now I know the reason why. Its because I have a header in my activesheet. As I test just now . It is working . Thanks a lot for this . Additional knowledge for me .

Comment: @sayjon (and future users) - if you have a header, you will need to change "G1" and "H1" to be "G2" and "H2" (or whatever row the data starts on)

Comment: Additional hint: the error is caused by trying to get a second token in the split array (via index 1), but there is no such 2nd partial string when there is no delimiter at all like in your heading. If you want execution including the headline or even empty strings,  you can avoid such errors by simply adding an additional delimiter to the original string to be splitted, e.g. `vR(i, 1) = Split(s & "/", "/")(1)`  or  `vR(i, 2) = Split(s & "X", "X")(1)`.

Comment: Hi @T.M. I will try and test your brilliant suggestion . thanks a lot ...